# Adjusting location of Main panel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have created the following UI using R shiny. The script is as follows.

The first part deals with the sidebar layout.

```
 ui <- fluidPage(  
 titlePanel("Graphingtool"),  
  h3("DB"),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(
  column(12,
       fluidRow(
         column(3,
                fileInput("file1", 'DB',
                          multiple = TRUE,
                          accept = c("xlsx/xls",".xls",".xlsx"))),# We have added the formats here- will load excel alone- in case csv/txt needed amend here
         column(5,
                column(4,downloadButton(outputId = "Downloaddata", label = "Downloader"))
         )
       ),
       fluidRow(
         column(3,
                textInput(inputId = 'T',label =  'T'),
                textInput(inputId = 'C',label =  'C'),
                textInput(inputId = "P", label = "P"),

                column(2, offset = 2,
                       actionButton(inputId = "CLS", label = "CLS"))
         ),
         column(5,
                textInput(inputId = "P", label = "P"),
                textInput(inputId = "Y", label = "Y"),
                numericInput(inputId = "Numberinput", label = "Ninput", min = -1000000000, max = 1000000000, value = 0,step = 1)
         )),
       fluidRow(
         column(3,
                radioButtons("dist", "Vertical Axis Scale",
                             c("Linear" = "Linear Reg",
                               "Log" = "Log reg"))),
         column(5,
                radioButtons("dist", "Horizontal Axis Scale",
                             c("Linear" = "Linear reg",
                               "Log" = "Log reg")))
       ),
       fluidRow(
         column(5,
                sliderInput(inputId = "Scale", label = "Scale", min = 0, max = 100, 
                            step = 2.5, value = 1))) ) )
```

## Here we create the main panel

```
 ,mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
  )))        



 server<-function(input, output){reactive({})}
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I Have created the main panel. However, the Panel with two tabs is opening under the sidebar panel and not on the right hand side of the panel.

The script works but is it possible to open the main panel on the right of the sidebar panel. I request someone to guide me here.

Comment: Do you want to keep all the columns in sidebar??

Comment: Yes. I understand I can Adjust the width but that has not helped Sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on this if this okay or not for you..

```
    library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Graphingtool"),  
  h3("DB"),
  hr(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
               fluidRow(
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        fileInput("file1", 'DB',
                                  multiple = TRUE,
                                  accept = c("xlsx/xls",".xls",".xlsx"))),# We have added the formats here- will load excel alone- in case csv/txt needed amend here
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        HTML('<br/>'),
                        column(4,downloadButton(outputId = "Downloaddata", label = "Downloader"))
                 )
               ),
               fluidRow(
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        textInput(inputId = 'T',label =  'T'),
                        textInput(inputId = 'C',label =  'C'),
                        textInput(inputId = "P", label = "P"),

                        column(2, offset = 2,
                               ailgn="center",
                               actionButton(inputId = "CLS", label = "CLS"))
                 ),
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        textInput(inputId = "P", label = "P"),
                        textInput(inputId = "Y", label = "Y"),
                        numericInput(inputId = "Numberinput", label = "Ninput", min = -1000000000, max = 1000000000, value = 0,step = 1)
                 )),
               HTML('<br/>'),
               fluidRow(
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        radioButtons("dist", "Vertical Axis Scale",
                                     c("Linear" = "Linear Reg",
                                       "Log" = "Log reg"))),
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        radioButtons("dist", "Horizontal Axis Scale",
                                     c("Linear" = "Linear reg",
                                       "Log" = "Log reg")))
               ),
               fluidRow(
                 column(5,
                        ailgn="center",
                        sliderInput(inputId = "Scale", label = "Scale", min = 0, max = 100, 
                                    step = 2.5, value = 1))) 

    )
    ,mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
      ))) 

    )
server<-function(input, output){reactive({})}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

You can tweak the size by adjusting column

Comment: This seems OK sir. Can U explain how it works. I think the widths have been adjusted

Comment: I have just edited the code for better positioning.you have not used sidebarlayout(). I request you to go through [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) for shiny layout. For dashboard you can explore [here](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/index.html)